# How to add space between views

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 3 elements in my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="125px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Los Santos"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="125px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I want the two buttons at the sides of the layout and the textView in the middle of the layout, but I don't know if there's a possibility of leaving a space between them without using margins.

It should look something like this (I have to edit the buttons but first I want to figure out how to distribute them in the layout):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better use ConstrainLayout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="125px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Los Santos"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="125px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the docs about it https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 1):

Use Constraint Layout. It is a very simple yet versatile layout which will help you with complicated arrangements.

A quick tutorial for Constraint Layout
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout?